# SQL - How to query multiple tables via a link ./ associative table

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables, linked-tables

I have a problem with querying multiple SQL tables and getting the results joined correctly.  I have 3 tables 1) a main table with articles, 2) a table with a list of subject tags, and 3) an associative table that links tags to articles.
I tried to construct the following query:
- Query a main table
- For each result get the associated tags in a 3rd table (linked by an associative table)
- Where there are no tags associated still include the results from the main table ( I tried various joins)

I have spend a couple of days trying and probably read over 30 posts on stackexchange but still have the problem that I can't both return all results and get the tags correctly associated with the records in the main table.  I have tried left / outer / inner joints but they will all return all tags for all records, not associate them correctly.

Here is the first example where the results are correct but all available tags are added to each record.
[Results correct but tags wrong [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahhI3.jpg)

Here is the second example where tags are correctly associated with results but results with no tags are not returned
[Tags correct but results with no tags not included [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGatG.jpg)

Here is one SQL code (corresponding to the second screen shot).

```
SELECT 
    Ar.Title, 
    Ar.Analysis_CategoryLevelOne_Name AS MainCategory, 
    Ar.Analysis_CategoryLevelTwo_Name AS SubCategory, 
    null AS GenericName, 
    Ar.Summary,
    Ar.Author AS Source,
    'Article' AS ContentType, 
    MATCH (Ar.Title, Summary, Content)
    AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Su.Name) AS Tags
    FROM `conArticles` AS Ar,
    `refSubjectTags` AS Su,
    `linkArticlesToSubjectTags` AS Link
    WHERE MATCH (Title, Summary, Content)
    AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND CurrentOrBackup = 'Current'
    AND Ar.Articles_id = Link.linkArticlesToSubjectTags_Articles_Id
    AND Link.linkArticlesToSubjectTags_SubjectTags_Id = Su.SubjectTags_Id
    GROUP BY Ar.Articles_Id
    ORDER BY 'Relevance' 'DESC';
```

I would greatly appreciate help with how to both get all results and the tags correctly associated with the records in the main table.

UPDATE:  After suggestions to try two left joins, I have below revised query.  Whilst I now get all the correct results from the main table, all the tags are associated with each result, which is not what I want (the output is shown in the first image attached).  Regarding the table structure, it corresponds to the one Nosyara posed i.e. I have an intermediate/associative table which only contains id pairs between the main and the tags table ( Articles_Id <=> SubjectTags_Id ). I have added a screen shot of the associative table [Associative table [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xInDD.jpg)

```
SELECT 
    Ar.Title, 
    Ar.Analysis_CategoryLevelOne_Name AS MainCategory, 
    Ar.Analysis_CategoryLevelTwo_Name AS SubCategory, 
    null AS GenericName, 
    Ar.Summary,
    Ar.Author AS Source,
    'Article' AS ContentType, 
    MATCH (Ar.Title, Summary, Content)
    AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance,    
    GROUP_CONCAT(Su.Name) AS Tags
    FROM    `refSubjectTags` AS Su,
    `conArticles` AS Ar
    LEFT JOIN linkArticlesToSubjectTags Link
    ON Ar.Articles_id = Link.linkArticlesToSubjectTags_Articles_Id
    LEFT JOIN refSubjectTags Su2
    ON Link.linkArticlesToSubjectTags_SubjectTags_Id = Su2.SubjectTags_Id
    WHERE MATCH (Title, Summary, Content)
    AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    GROUP BY Ar.Articles_Id
    ORDER BY 'Relevance' 'DESC';
```

NOTE: This has been solved. See correct code further down under Answers.

Comment: Based on your description, this sounds like an outer join to me.  Perhaps if you add the schema's of the tables, that would make it easier to form a query. An example dataset would also help. Also, if you add conditions in the `WHERE` clause, it applies to the entire dataset. Instead you would want the conditions in the `ON` clause of the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 left joins.

Here I created simplified schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main` ( `title` varchar(200));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` ( id int(10), `Name` varchar(200));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` ( `title` varchar(200),  `tag` int(10));

INSERT INTO main VALUES ('Foo'),  ('Bar'),  ('Baz');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (1, 'tag1'), (2, 'tag2'), (3, 'tag3'), (4, 'tag4');
INSERT INTO links VALUES ('Foo', 1), ('Foo', 2), ('Bar', 3),  ('Bar', 4),  ('Hello', 5), ('Foo', 6);
```

And this is SQL:

```
select ar.title, group_concat(t.name) as tags 
from main ar 
left join links lnk on ar.title=lnk.title 
left join tags t on lnk.tag = t.id
group by title
```

Output:

```
title    tags
-----    -----
Bar      tag3,tag4
Baz      (null)
Foo      tag1,tag2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a14ef4/1

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Your schema for the 3 tables corresponds to mine but  when I try the two left joins, whist I do get all the correct results from the main table all the tags are associated with all the results, which is not the desired result.  I will add my changes to the original question.

Comment: In my example I using 'title' as id.

Comment: I just made it work.  Your example also made me realise that I had declared the tags table twice, once after the initial select clause an once in the left join.  Apparently this caused the association of the tags data not to work correctly.  Once I remove it from the select clause it works.  I will post the solution.  Many thanks Nosyara

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to 1) add two left joins, 2) move the declaration of the SubjectTags table to the 2nd LEFT JOIN, 3) move the declaration of the the linkArticlesToSubjectTags table to the 1st LEFT JOIN, and 4) move the table ids associations from the WHERE CLAUSE into the LEFT JOINS.

Below is the correct code:

```
SELECT 
    Ar.Title, 
    Ar.Analysis_CategoryLevelOne_Name AS MainCategory, 
    Ar.Analysis_CategoryLevelTwo_Name AS SubCategory, 
    null AS GenericName, 
    Ar.Summary,
    Ar.Author AS Source,
    'Article' AS ContentType, 
    MATCH (Ar.Title, Summary, Content)
    AGAINST ('employ*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance,   
    GROUP_CONCAT(Su.Name) AS Tags
    FROM `conArticles` AS Ar
    LEFT JOIN linkArticlesToSubjectTags Link
    ON Ar.Articles_id = Link.linkArticlesToSubjectTags_Articles_Id
    LEFT JOIN refSubjectTags Su
    ON Link.linkArticlesToSubjectTags_SubjectTags_Id = Su.SubjectTags_Id
    WHERE MATCH (Title, Summary, Content)
    AGAINST ('employ*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    GROUP BY Ar.Articles_Id
    ORDER BY 'Relevance' 'DESC';
```

The following is the original incorrect code:

```
SELECT 
    Ar.Title, 
    Ar.Analysis_CategoryLevelOne_Name AS MainCategory, 
    Ar.Analysis_CategoryLevelTwo_Name AS SubCategory, 
    null AS GenericName, 
    Ar.Summary,
    Ar.Author AS Source,
    'Article' AS ContentType, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(Su.Name) AS Tags
    FROM    
    `refSubjectTags` Su, **[ Move to 2nd LEFT JOIN ]**
    `conArticles` Ar,
    `linkArticlesToSubjectTags` Link **[ Move to 1st LEFT JOIN ]**
    **[ Add the 2 LEFT JOINS ]**
    WHERE MATCH (Title, Summary, Content)
    AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    AND Ar.Articles_id = Link.linkArticlesToSubjectTags_Articles_Id
    AND Link.linkArticlesToSubjectTags_SubjectTags_Id = Su.SubjectTags_Id
    **[ The 2 lines above needs to be moved to the 2 LEFT JOINS ]**
    GROUP BY Ar.Articles_Id
    ORDER BY 'Relevance' 'DESC';
```